# Sacar datos de la fila de una imagen guardada en una base de datos al dar click en ella

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, mysqli

He sacado las imágenes de mi base de datos que estaban guardadas con el texto "coche.jpg" por pantalla y al darlas click sale un texto debajo, quiero que al dar click encima de una de ellas me saque la fila con los datos de esa imagen en el recuadro, con el while he conseguido que saque por pantalla todas las imágenes de la tabla, después igualo en la consulta la imagen de la tabla con el row['imagen'] pero al dar click en cualquiera de ellas solo me sale la última fila de la tabla y me he quedado atascado aquí, alguien sabe como solucionarlo, gracias.

```
<body>
    <figure>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row mb-1 p-2">
                <h2 style="text-align:center">Vehículos</h2>
            </div>
            
            <div class="row mb-1 p-2">
                <a href="nuevovehiculo.php" class="btn btn-primary">Nuevo Vehículo</a>
            </div>
            
            <br>
            <script languague="javascript">
        function mostrar() {
            div = document.getElementById('flotante');
            div.style.display = '';
        }

        function cerrar() {
            div = document.getElementById('flotante');
            div.style.display = 'none';
        }
</script>
<?php
    require 'db.php';
    $usuario=$_SESSION["username"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM vehiculos where usuarios_username='$usuario'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    
?>
<?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {    extract($row);
?>
            <p><a href="javascript:mostrar();"><img style="width:200px; height:150px" src="images/<?php echo $row['imagen'];$img=$row['imagen']; ?>"></a></p>
            <?php } ?>

<article id="flotante" style="display:none;">
     <article id="close"><a href="javascript:cerrar();">cerrar</a></article>
            <div style="width: 100%" class="row table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Imágen</th>
                            <th>Número de bastidor</th>
                            <th>Marca</th>
                            <th>Modelo</th>
                            <th>Homologación</th>
                            <th>Procedencia</th>
                            <th>Combustible</th>
                            <th>Precio Combustible</th>                            
                            <th>Usuario</th>                         
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    
                    <tbody>
                    <?php
    require 'db.php';
    $usuario=$_SESSION["username"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM vehiculos where usuarios_username='$usuario' and imagen='$img' ";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    
?>
                        <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {    extract($row);
?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><img src="images/<?php echo $row['imagen']; ?>"  class="img-rounded" width="50px" height="50px"/></td>
                                <td><img src="images/<?php echo $row['imagen']; ?>"  class="img-rounded" width="50px" height="50px"/></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['num_bastidor']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['marca']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['modelo']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['contr_homologacion'];?</td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['procedencia']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['gasolina']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['precio_gas']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['usuarios_username']; ?></td>
                                <td><a href="#" data-href="eliminarvehiculo.php?num_bastidor=<?php echo $row['num_bastidor']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>

                                <td><a href="#" data-href="eliminarvehiculo.php?num_bastidor=<?php echo $row['num_bastidor']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        </article>
```

Así es como he cambiado el código:

```
<figure>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row mb-1 p-2">
                <h2 style="text-align:center">Vehículos</h2>
            </div>
            
            <div class="row mb-1 p-2">
                <a href="nuevovehiculo.php" class="btn btn-primary">Nuevo Vehículo</a>
            </div>
            
            <br>
 <script languague="javascript">
        var iPos = 0; // Variable global donde guardaremos el valor de $i (de PHP que se genera dentro de "Mostrar"

        function mostrar(pIPos) {
            iPos=pIPos;
            div = document.getElementById('flotante' + iPos);
            div.style.display = '';
        }

        function cerrar() {
            div = document.getElementById('flotante' + iPos); // Usamos el valor antes colocado
            div.style.display = 'none';
        }   
</script>
<?php
    require 'db.php';
    $usuario=$_SESSION["username"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM vehiculos where usuarios_username='$usuario'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    
?>
<?php
    $i=0;
    while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    extract($row); /* en lo personal este "extract" no le veo uses su resultado; desde luego en el código que compartes */
?>
    <p>
        <a href="javascript:mostrar(<?php echo $i; ?>);">
                <img style="width:200px; height:150px" 
                    src="images/<?php echo $row['imagen'];$img=$row['imagen']; ?>">
        </a>
    </p>
<?php $i++; } ?>
<?php
    require 'db.php';
    $usuario=$_SESSION["username"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM vehiculos where usuarios_username='$usuario' and imagen='$img' ";
    $resultado= mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    
?>
<article >
     <article id="close"><a href="javascript:cerrar(<?php echo $i; ?>);">cerrar</a></article>
            <div style="width: 100%" class="row table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
                    <thead> 

                    <tr >
                            <th>Imágen</th>
                            <th>Número de bastidor</th>
                            <th>Marca</th>
                            <th>Modelo</th>
                            <th>Homologación</th>
                            <th>Procedencia</th>
                            <th>Combustible</th>
                            <th>Precio Combustible</th>                            
                            <th>Usuario</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    
                    <tbody>
<?php
   $i=0;    
   while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      extract($row); /* Idem de while anterior */
      /* A continuación los tr y contenidos del tbody */
?>


                            <tr id="flotante<?php echo $i; ?>" style="display:none;">
                                <td><img src="images/<?php echo $row['imagen']; ?>"  class="img-rounded" width="50px" height="50px"/></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['num_bastidor']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['marca']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['modelo']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['contr_homologacion']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['procedencia']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['gasolina']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['precio_gas']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['usuarios_username']; ?></td>
                                <td><a href="#" data-href="eliminarvehiculo.php?num_bastidor=<?php echo $row['num_bastidor']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php $i++;} ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A tus funciones `mostrar` y `cerrar` agrega que reciban un parámetro (en este caso se considera es un valor entero).

Ahora, asumiendo que al ejecutar la sentencia `$sql = "SELECT * FROM vehiculos where usuarios_username='$usuario'";` las dos veces que invocas `$resultado = mysqli_query($con, $sql);` devuelven los datos en el mismo orden. Declara e inicializa una variable (consideremos) `$i=0` antes de cada `while` y al final de este incrementarlo (es decir `$i++;`).

Para cada vez que pones `href="javascript:mostrar();"` le agregas el valor de `$i`; tal que, quede algo así; `href="javascript:mostrar(<?php echo $i; ?>);"`; lo mismo para `cerrar` solo que como tienes un solo **cerrar** deberás cambiarlo para que sea en cada imagen.

Otra opción, dejando el parámetro en `mostrar` es realices lo siguiente:

```
var iPos = 0; // Variable global donde guardaremos el valor de $i (de PHP que se genera dentro de "Mostrar"

function mostrar(pIPos) {
    iPos=pIPos;
    div = document.getElementById('flotante' + iPos);
    div.style.display = '';
}

function cerrar() {
    div = document.getElementById('flotante' + iPos); // Usamos el valor antes colocado
    div.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Esto tiene el inconveniente que se deberá cerrar primero la información anterior (ya sea lo hagas por código o asumas que el usuario la cerro) ya que `iPos` solo tiene un valor y es de la información inmediata mostrada; por tanto, deberás muy seguramente realizar cambios en tu código para lograr el efecto deseado, desde luego acorde a como manejes tus escenarios.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Conforme a comentario que sigue mostrando la última hay dos cosas que considerar:

- El `id` ya no debe ser en el tag `<article>`; debe ser en el `<tr`> en el 2do `while`.
- El `<tr>` (del `while` antes mencionado) debe ir con el `id`; pero agregando el `$i`; es decir `<tr id="flotante<?php echo $i; ?>" style="display:none;">`.

Espero no me falte nada más.

**GUÍA -Actualización-**

La parte de JavaScript

```
var iPos = 0; // Variable global donde guardaremos el valor de $i (de PHP que se genera dentro de "Mostrar"

function mostrar(pIPos) {
    iPos=pIPos;
    div = document.getElementById('flotante' + iPos);
    div.style.display = '';
}

function cerrar() {
    div = document.getElementById('flotante' + iPos); // Usamos el valor antes colocado
    div.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Veo que quitaste un `while` no era necesario.

Era solo:

```
/* Esto así como esta -acorde a la lógica que "identifique"- */
<?php
    $i=0;
    while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    extract($row); /* en lo personal este "extract" no le veo uses su resultado; desde luego en el código que compartes */
?>
    <p>
        <a href="javascript:mostrar(<?php echo $i; ?>);">
                <img style="width:200px; height:150px" 
                    src="images/<?php echo $row['imagen'];$img=$row['imagen']; ?>">
        </a>
    </p>
<?php $i++; } ?>
```

> El `$img` que asignas y usas (en tu código) compartidos mas abajo; siempre tendrá el último valor del `while` (de arriba).

```
<?php
   require 'db.php';
   $usuario=$_SESSION["username"];
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM vehiculos where usuarios_username='$usuario' and imagen='$img' "; /* De este $img ver comentario arriba */ 
   $resultado = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
?>
<!-- TAGs de inicio hasta el tbody -->

<?php
   $i=0;    
   while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      extract($row); /* Idem de while anterior */
      /* A continuación los tr y contenidos del tbody */
?>
   <tr id="flotante<?php echo $i; ?>" style="display:none;">
      <!-- Solo pongo el primero para que completes lo demás -->
      <td>
         <img src="images/<?php echo $row['imagen']; ?>" 
            class="img-rounded" width="50px" height="50px"/>
      </td>
   </tr>
<?php
      $i++;
   }
?>
<!-- No olvides cerrar los tag que abristes -->
```

**GUÍA 2 -Actualización-**

A continuación mi sugerencia en atención a tu comentario; (ojo es sugerencia conforme lo "veo" y mi lógica) desde luego espero te sirva.

Del primer bloque de PHP agregar variable `$imgs` de tipo array (arreglo); iniciarlizarla en vacía y dentro del `while` donde se invoca `mostrar` se llenara:

```
/* Esto así como esta -acorde a la lógica que "identifique"- */
<?php
    $imgs=array(); /* Declaramos el array */
    /* Para simplificar omito la ya conocido */
    while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      /* Todo el código ya conocido */
      $imgs[]=$row['imagen']; /* Agregamos la imagen (1) */
      $i++; 
    } 
?>
```

> (1) Esta parte "hoy" la tienes en  `src="images/<?php echo $row['imagen'];$img=$row['imagen']; ?>">`

A continuación usaremos el `$imgs` que previamente poblamos.

```
<?php
   require 'db.php';
   $usuario=$_SESSION["username"];
?>
<!-- TAGs de inicio hasta el tbody -->
<?php
   /* Usare el for; el foreach no lo he usado */
   $totalImagenes= count($imgs); // Total de elementos Imagenes existentes
   $j=0;
   $i=0;
   for ($j=0; $j<$totalImagenes; $j++) {
      $img=$imgs[$j]; /* Aquí ya tendrás cada una de las imagenes del anterior while en misma variable $img */
      /* A continuación $sql como lo tienes por cada imagen; que esta antes del while */
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM vehiculos where usuarios_username='$usuario' and imagen='$img' "; /* aquí usas la variable $img como en tu código original */ 
      /* Aquí el while con el que formas cada tr y sus hijos */
   }

?>
<!-- No olvides cerrar los tag que abristes -->
```

Solo cuida de trasladar lo que ya tienes a los aquí sugerido y (en lo posible) explicado que va.

Comment: Lo he intentado con la primera opción, no se si lo habré hecho bien porque me sigue sacando la última fila de la tabla. Te dejo el primer while a ver si es esto lo que me indicabas ` <?php $i=0; while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {    extract($row);
?>
            <p><a href="javascript:mostrar(<?php echo $i; ?>);"><img style="width:200px; height:150px" src="images/<?php echo $row['imagen'];$img=$row['imagen']; ?>"></a></p>
            <?php $i++; } ?>`

Comment: Saludos. Actualizando; me falto una parte la que corresponde al ´id="flotante"´ referenciar cambio.

Comment: Ahora me sigue saliendo la última fila pero directamente sin dar click a la foto, no se porque puede ser

Comment: Saludos. Debajo de lo que actualmente esta; pon el código como lo tienes ahora.

Comment: Ya he puesto la actualización del código, a ver si me puedes ayudar a solucionarlo ya que me esta volviendo loco, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Saludos. De la actualización @ManoloRamírez te comento la función `mostrar` y `cerrar` siguen siendo las mismas, lo que sugerí en mis respuesta y añadí como **ACTUALIZACIÓN** no se observa implementado, el uso `href="javascript:cerrar(<?php echo $i; ?>);"` debe estar en el 2do `while` (para estar con cada imagen) de lo contrario usa el `cerrar` que no recibe parámetro. *De momento es lo que puedo observar*.

Comment: He actualizado el código y he añadido una imagen de la página

Comment: He vuelto a actualizar la información sigue sacándome la última fila, y ahora al dar click en la segunda foto no ocurre nada, como debería cambiar la variable $img para que no me pase lo del último valor y me saque el valor de la imagen que doy click?. Te vuelvo a dar las gracias por las molestias

Comment: Siento molestarle pero no he conseguido acabarlo, podrías decirme como cambiar la variable $img para que cada vez que de click en una imagen me salga la información de esa imagen, gracias

Comment: acabo de poner a prueba la actualización, funciona bien pero me saca la información de todas las filas, puede ser porque el array almacena todas las imágenes en $img?

Comment: Usa un ciclo for (como el que inclui) para solamente imprimir el `$img` *(que resulta de `$img=$imgs[$j];' así comprobaras que trae en cada iteracción `$img`. Igual en dado caso entendi mal tu código, esta mal lo que puse o tu lógica que compartiste no refleja realmente el proceso a realizarse.

Comment: puede ser que mi planteamiento este mal, yo creo que lo que se necesita es que al dar click en una imagen se saque el nombre de esa imagen y pasarlo al $img  de la sentencia sql y así sacar la información de esa imagen en el "flotante" de esa imagen, pero no se muy bien como hacerlo

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. como tal lo que es código **PHP** solo existe del lado del servidor; por tanto **"[...] pasarlo al $img de la sentencia sql y así sacar la información de esa imagen [...]** no sería realizable (por estan en el mismo script php que se ejecuta). Pero como te comente, lo que propuse fue acorde a tu código como lo entendi. Suerte.